# How can I use regex to require a complex, varying structure?

Tags: java, regex

I have a few Strings like so:

> text {TAG_A:text|TAG_B:text} text {TAG_A:text|TAG_B:text} text ...

Or

> text {TAG_A:text|TAG_C:text|TAG_D} {TAG_A:text|TAG_D:text} text text ...

Or maybe even

> {TAG_B:text|TAG_A:text} text {TAG_D:text|TAG_B:text|TAG_A:text} text text ...

There is no fixed pattern to the alternating of the non-braced and braced groups, and it can start with either sort.

A 'valid' braced group in this context implies that the braced group has at least TAG_A **and** one of the other TAGs (TAGs will always have the same name and upper-case). Only TAG_A through TAG_D exists. Each TAG must be followed by a colon ':' and at least one character after that (any character). Since each group will require at least 2 TAGs, there will always be at least one pipe '|' seperating them, and additional pipes for each other TAG included. There is also no order to the TAGs in the brace.

There are 2 things I'd need to do here with regex. Firstly, I need a regex that can determine if there are any 'valid' braced groups. Secondly, a regex that can be looped over with Java's Matcher.find() for each 'valid' braced group.

I'm not as concerned with capturing the non-braced groups, but it'd still be nice if that's possible. Just tell me if I've left something vague, will try to clarify, and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Firstly this looks suspiciously like markup, and regex is not the right tool for that. Secondly, I'd recommend you show your attempts.

Comment: `Each TAG must be followed by a colon ':' and at least one character after that (any character).` By `any character` you also mean `}` or `|` or `:`?

Comment: There lies my problem XD I can't get it not to incude the characters I'm using to delimit tags or groups. And I've had far too many failed attempts, they all end up horribly messy and confusing. I'm not sure what you mean by markup though. If there's a better way than regex, I'm all for it.

Comment: The problem with your current question is that it shows **no** attempt at actually solving the problem - all you did is state the problem you're trying to solve - since people like to downvote and close such questions, it's generally a good idea to at least include *something* in terms of an attempt.

Comment: Sorry @Dukeling, I figured that'd be the case, but my attempts weren't worth posting given my extremely limited experience with regex, but that's why I post here, to try to get that sorted out. Think I pretty much destroyed my attempts prior to this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern should match the tags that you have described, including testing for the existence of `TAG_A`:

```
\{(TAG_[B-D]:[^|]+?\|)*TAG_A:[^|]+?(\|TAG_[B-D]:[^|]+?)*\}
```

Comment: Not that I am downvoter but this regex will not ensure existence of `TAG_A` which seems mandatory.

Comment: @Pshemo Good point :p Actually I see other problems as well, it doesn't ensure a closing `}`

Comment: Thanks! If I can sort this bit out, I'll see if I can't somehow apply it.

Comment: Note that this still doesn't work fully, [here](http://regexr.com?38gmh) it matches across 2 sets when A isn't present in the first

Comment: Instead of `[^|]` you can use `[^:|}]` to make your regex safer.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, that little tweak seems to have fixed the aforementioned issue!

Answer (score -1):

I don't really see the problem. You can match

```
{TAG_A:[^}]+}
```

Loop over the hits and figure out how many other tags there are by splitting on "|"?

Comment: "the braced group has at least TAG_A **and** one of the other TAGs... There is also **no order** to the TAGs in the brace."

Comment: The given regex supports multiple tags but it does assume tag_a to be first. If this is not a given, you need to check for {[^}]+}.

Comment: But it should **require** multiple tags